# How to remove all the duplicate results in Hibernate Search?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search, infinispan

I'm using Infinispan with 6.0.2 with Hibernate Search 4.4.0.

In the begining, after I execute a query like

```
CacheQuery cq = SearchManager.getQuery(query,Hibernate.class).projection("id");
```

I use the `cq.list()` to get "id".

But now the number of results reaches 300.000, because of the designing fo DB(cant change), the duplicate id is almost 29,000.

I wrote this to get "id":

```
for(int i=0;i<listObject.size();i++)
{
    Object[] rdf = (Object[])listObject.get(i);
    if(!result.contains((String) rdf[0])) 
       result.add((String) rdf[0]);
}
```

But even if I parallel this part, it also takes a long time.

Does there is a function to remove duplicate id for the query in Hibernate like the **DISTINCT** does in SQL?

Comment: Is the question not really why you have so many duplicates, ot are you saying that is expected? Can you describe the full use case?

Comment: E.g the Hibernate provides me 300.000 results which my query hits, the value of each "id" is all correct. But the "id" is not unique, so there are 290.000 id is duplicate. I was wondering if there is a method like **DISTINCT** for SQL in Infinispan. I saw the **Criteria** in hibernate, but I didn't know how to use in Infinispan. @Hardy

Answer (score -1):

setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)  use the distinct .

Comment: I didn' find a method to set the resultTransformer in Infinispan. Can u give me a example?

Comment: Criteria criteria2 = session.createCriteria(classname.class)
 .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")))
       .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
       .add(Restrictions.eq("clientName", userName))
       .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));

Comment: In fact, I saw this in hibernate. But I'm using hibernate in Infinispan, there isn't even a class called Criteria...

Comment: ResultTransformer is only available for normal Hibernate Criterias, not for Hibernate Search.